# What is wrong with my vue-multiselect options?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-multiselect

I have a vue-multiselect component in a form, and the console reports that my options are undefined, even though I can see they are not. My options are fetched from a back end and put in the store well before this component is created.

The console error is

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "options". Expected Array, got Undefined
```

Here is my component

```
<template>
  <form action="#" @submit.prevent>
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="subtitle">Details</h2>

        <b-field label="Role" horizontal>
          <multiselect
            :options="roleOptions"
            track-by="id"
            label="title"
            :multiple="true"
            :close-on-select="false"
            :clear-on-select="false"
          ></multiselect>
        </b-field>
      </div>
    </section>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";
import { mapState, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "ProcessDetailsComponent",
  components: {
    multiselect: Multiselect
  },
  computed: {
    roleOptions() {
      return this.$store.state.processes.formData.process_roles;
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

In the developer tools Vue inspector, I can see that the options look correct (to me). I've tried passing them in as props, computed values, mapped state - same problem every time.

[image]

If I swap the options out for a static array, defined in the data() function, it works ok. Can anyone confirm that I am implementing this correctly?

Comment: Seems to me that `this.$store.state.processes.formData.process_roles` is undefined, can you log its value and check it out?

Comment: You're right! It's the lifecycle - the options haven't returned from the back end when this is first rendered. They arrive later, but seems like the js errors have already broken the component by that time.

Comment: if (this.$store.state.processes.formData.process_roles.length > 0) {
  return this.$store.state.processes.formData.process_roles
}
return []

Comment: or try placing a v-cloak on the multiselect element

Comment: If you already have the latest multiselect library, try updating your vuejs library to 2.6 and above. That worked for me with undefined issue with custom-label

Answer (score 0):

:options="roleOptions" expects an array. Make sure the vue variable is an array and not an object or undefined etc as mentioned above.

```
 data(){
        return{
            roleOptions:[],
          }
       }
```